# How do you find who has approved the most merge requests GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

As it says on the tin, is it possible for me to find who has approved the most merge request in Git please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways, depending on whether you want to know based on a group or a project:

For a group, you select "Analytics > Contribution" and scroll down to "Contributions per Group Member", where you can sort by Approved MR count

For a project, you select "Merge Requests", then click the "Merged" tab and export it to CSV using the button in the upper right. Then you can open the CSV and create a chart using something like excel.